# How to make the inline block boxes vertical align to the top?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a custom thumbnail layout, and the content inside each item is not a same length, so the alignment of the thumbnails becomes either up or down. Any suggestion to align them all to the top?

[image: Alignment like this example bellow]

```css
.item{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
  margin-right:10px;
  }

.item img{
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
    padding:5px;
  background-color:#454545;
    border:1px solid #454545;
  }

.info{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:14px;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `.item {vertical-align:top;}`. Because of the default vertical alignment of an inline box is `baseline`.

```css
.item{
  vertical-align: top;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
  margin-right:10px;
  }

.item img{
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
    padding:5px;
  background-color:#454545;
    border:1px solid #454545;
  }

.info{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:14px;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `.item` - `vertical-align: top`

```css
.item{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
  margin-right:10px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

.item img{
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
    padding:5px;
  background-color:#454545;
    border:1px solid #454545;
  }

.info{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:14px;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451012500/4628fbb9dc70514d389ed9491243866f_400x400.png" />
    <div class="info">Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```